# php variables GET

Tags: php, mysql, file-get-contents

I am stuck on getting something working. Basically I want to be able to do file.php?ip=132.123.123.123&port=28005

basically i want filegetcontents to embed the text

[image]

is what I want (Shows offline because of syntax error because I Can't get the when its online it returns in plain text online / offline

```
Print "<td>".file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/status.php?ip=".$ip?port=.$port);" </td></tr>";
```

its grabbing from the database the ip and the port and the status checker checks on file.php?ip=132.123.123.123&port=28005

---

Below doing it I get this error

```
[03-Jan-2014 03:46:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  fsockopen() [<a href='function.fsockopen'>function.fsockopen</a>]: unable to connect to udp://123.123.123.123?port=28035:0 (Failed to parse address &quot;123.123.123.123?port=28035&quot;) in /home/*/public_html/servers/status.php on line 5
```

The line im using

```
Print "<td>".file_get_contents("http://www.domain.me/servers/status.php?ip=".$info['ip']."?port=".$info['port']) ." </td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple quoting issues and an erroneous semi-colon:

```
Print "<td>".file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/status.php?ip=".$ip?port=.$port);" </td></tr>";
```

should be

```
Print "<td>".file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/status.php?ip=".$ip."?port=".$port) ." </td></tr>";
```

A decent text editor would have caught the quoting issue and an IDE would have caught the semi-colon issue.

As for creating the table, that will depend on the format of the data you get back from `file_get_contents()`. Do a `var_dump()` on that data and see what format it is in so you can plan how to approach making your table.

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/status.php?ip=".$ip."?port=".$port);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Sorry I left out a part of the code, I already have the database, I Want to take the port from .$info['port'] and .$info['ip']

Any Idea?

Comment: any Idea about that? Querying from the MYSQL table? for the IP and Port

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual issue is. You seem to know how to write the query and what the names of the variables are for those two parameters. What isn't working?

Comment: check my reply to the question on main post